# Appending in Modelbuilder to a derived dataset

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, modelbuilder

I have a simple model with a file gdb model parameter `InputGDB`, which contains a feature class `fc1`. Inside the model is a preset output folder and a template (empty) file gdb `TemplateGDB`, which contains a feature dataset `template_fds` and a feature class `template_fc`. A copy of `TemplateGDB` is made in the output folder and takes its name from `InputGDB` (using inline variables).

I would like to Append `fc1` into `template_fc` with the schema set to `NO_TEST`. However, since the target dataset `template_fc` does not exist yet because the model hasn't run, the Append tool will obviously not validate. Is there a way for me to run the model without having to first run the first section, then validating to run the Append process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After numerous tests with `Append` in various models (and after my colleagues encountered the same problem), we found that `Append` will not accept an target that does not exist yet (even though the inline variables are filled in). As a workaround, I now have to append into a scratch feature class and copy it over to my output later in the model.